# SymmetricDS: Could not find trigger router sym_file_snapshot

Tags: symmetricds

I'm doing 3-tier file synchronization. Let say the tier is `Corp - Store - Device`. I'm also doing it like 3-tier database synchronization. I create `trigger`, `router`, and `trigger_router` for `Corp - Store` and `Store - Device`.

But appeared error `TriggerRouterService - Could not find triger router [sym_file_snapshot] in list [sym_file_snapshot]`.
After I found out, the error is the `Corp` node wants to connect to `Device` node. What's wrong here? Is my approach wrong?

Update:

1. `Corp` node wants to send initial load to `Device` node directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `sym_node_security` and look at `initial_load_enabled` is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `sym_router` routes files from Corp to Device directly. Create two `sym_routers`:

1. first one to route files from Corp's `corp_directory` to Store's `store_directory`
2. second one to route file from Store's `store_directory` to Device's `device_directory`

Comment: yes, I already did. Update: `Corp` node wants to send initial load to `Device` node directly. Must I delete `Device` node existence from `Corp` and register it manually at `Store` node?

Comment: `Corp` can't send initial load directly to `Device`. First it has to go to `Store` and then the `Store` sends the initial load to `Device`

Comment: yes, but the fact is `DataService - Queueing up an initial load to Device node` at `Corp` node and after that the above exception is appeared

Comment: because there's a `sym_router` that routes those files from `Corp` to a `Device` not to a `Store`

Comment: I did double cross-check and found `sym_router` is correct. I did little research: First, I only add `Corp` and `Store` node, and also `router`, `trigger`, and `trigger_router`. The result is fine. Second, I add `Device` node (`node_group`, `group_link`, `node`, `node_security`) without `router`, `trigger`, and `trigger_router`, the exception is appearing.

Comment: So I think, node can send initial node to everything in `sym_node`. Just my speculation.

Comment: No, it sends the initial load only to routed targets. What's the group link for the device?

Comment: `Store - Device` is P and also `Device - Store` is P

Comment: ah I know, at `sym_node_security` the `initial_load_enabled` is set, so the master node send initial load to others, although no `router` is set

Comment: how to turn this comment become useful for other?

Comment: Create an answer or edit the question adding a section: SOLUTION